# Efficient algorithms for minimization of bi-linear matrix expressions?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, soft-question, homotopy-theory, nonlinear-optimization

Say I want to solve $$\min_{\bf x}\|\bf Ax-b\|_2^2$$
This problem is well defined and easy to solve using linear least squares. But what if we suddenly have

$$\min_{\bf x,A}\|\bf Ax-b\|_2^2$$

Looking at $\bf x$ and $\bf A$ separately this is as simple as the above problem, but what about now when we allow both to vary?

---

**Own work**

A naive approach I have tried which seems to work well enough in some cases is to simply do alternatingly solving:

$${\bf x}_k \text{ from } \min_{\bf x}\|{\bf Ax-b}\|_2^2\hspace{1cm} {\bf A}_k \text{ from } \min_{\bf A}\|{\bf Ax-b}\|_2^2$$

Maybe if we assume "sufficient niceness" in some sense of $\bf b$ then this would guarantee to give optimum? Or if we take small enough steps we can refer to the idea of continuation? In other words regularizing

$${\bf x}_k \text{ from } \min_{\bf x}\|{\bf Ax-b}\|_2^2 + \epsilon \|{\bf x-x}_{k-1}\|_2^2$$

And analogously for $\bf A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that,
$$
A
=
\begin{bmatrix}
| & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
b & \vdots & & \vdots \\
| & 0 & \cdots & 0
\end{bmatrix}
,~~
x = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
satisfies $Ax = b$.

More generally, whenever $x\neq0$ you you can always find $A$ so that $Ax=b$ but having one of the columns of $A$ be an appropriately scaled version of $b$. However, since you have this as an interpediate step in your current approach, perhaps I have not understood what you are trying to do.

Comment: You found the simplest answer to the question, so I should not punish you for it, but you are right i was looking for something deeper.